# ghostscript PDF to Png crop x and y

Tags: c#, vb.net, ghostscript.net

i use ghostscript for my convertion PDF to PNG in vb.net when i crop my pdf then i convert this in png but ghostscript keep x and y position cropping in my picture.

I have solved this problem when i use gswin64.exe in cmd with : `-c "<</Install {-48 -87 translate}>> setpagedevice"`

but with dll Ghostcript.NET when i add this command in my code : `oGSImage.CustomSwitches.Add("-c ""<</Install {-48 -87 translate}>> setpagedevice""")` i have error message

> Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptAPICallException: An error occured when call to 'gsapi_init_with_args' is made: -100

my device is pngAlpha, if anyone could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution :
Initialize variable with the desired crop values

```
Dim nLeft as integer = 20
Dim nRight as integer = 20
Dim nBoth as integer = 40
Dim nUp as integer = 20
```

i created rasterize object with Ghostscript.NET dll : 
I Get Height and width size page without CustomSwitches ("-dPDFFitPage")

```
Dim rasterize As Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer = New Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer()
    rasterize.Open("PDFPath")
    Dim nHeightBased As Integer = rasterize.GetPage(72, 72, 1).Height
    Dim nWidthBased As Integer = rasterize.GetPage(72, 72, 1).Width
    rasterize.Close()
```

then, i create a new rasterize for get height and width size page with CustomSwitches ("-dPDFFitPage")

```
        rasterize = New Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer()
        rasterize.CustomSwitches.Add("-dPDFFitPage")
        rasterize.Open(cPathPDF)

        Dim nHeightBound As Integer = nHeightBased - rasterize.GetPage(72, 72, 1).Height
        Dim nWidthBound As Integer = nWidthBased - rasterize.GetPage(72, 72, 1).Width
        Dim nWidthPDF As Integer = rasterize.GetPage(72, 72, 1).Width
        Dim nHeightPDF As Integer = rasterize.GetPage(72, 72, 1).Height
        rasterize.Close()

        Dim nWidthCrop As Integer = (nWidthPDF + nWidthBound) - (nLeft + nRight)
        Dim nHeightCrop As Integer = (nHeightPDF + (nHeightBound / 2)) - (nBoth + nUp)

        CropPDF("PathPDF", nLeft, nBoth, nWidthCrop, nHeightCrop)
```

And i Create function CropPDF :

> Now we take gswinc32.exe or gswinc64.exe and .dll and copy/paste in a new path in my example i use "PathEXE"

```
Public Function CropPDF(ByVal cPathPDF As String, ByVal nLeft As Integer, ByVal nBoth As Integer, ByVal nWidthCrop As Integer, ByVal nHeightCrop As Integer)

    Dim cPathWithoutExtension = Path.GetDirectoryName("PDFPath") & "/" & Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("PDFPath")

    Dim gsPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PathEXE")
        Dim gsArgsList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        gsArgsList.Add("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite")
        gsArgsList.Add(" -dFIXEDMEDIA")
        gsArgsList.Add(" -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=" & nWidthCrop)
        gsArgsList.Add(" -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=" & nHeightCrop)
        gsArgsList.Add(" -o """ & cPathWithoutExtension & "_Crop.pdf""")
        gsArgsList.Add(" -c ""<</Install {-" & nLeft & " -" & nBoth & " translate} >> setpagedevice """)
        gsArgsList.Add(" -f " & cPathPDF)

        Dim gsArgs As String = String.Join(Nothing, gsArgsList)

        Process.Start(gsPath, gsArgs).WaitForExit()

        Dim OFI As FileInfo = New FileInfo(cPathPDF)
        OFI.Delete()

        Dim DestOFI As FileInfo = New FileInfo(cPathWithoutExtension & "_Crop.pdf")
        DestOFI.MoveTo(cPathPDF)

        Return cPath

End Function
```

Now perfect work with nLeft nRight nBoth nUp crop, hoping that it will help some people :D

Answer (score 0):

That particular argument executes PostScript from the command line, it isn't strictly a 'switch' as such. Get it in the wrong place and it won't work, and the interpreer will exit. My guess is that (or similar) is what is happening, the interpreter isn't being fed the data the way it wants.

You could put the text between the -c "" -f into a text file and then run that file **and** then PDF file on the command line (ie as arguments) if Ghostscript.NET lets you do that.